# How to group the powers of one variable?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Consider the following expression:

$\sqrt{a x} \sqrt{b x}$

What do I use to make it simplify to:

$\sqrt{ab} x$

I tried actually everything (Simplify, FullSimplify, Collect and so on...) and such expressions remain unchanged.

Thanks in Advance and Regards,

Misery

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `PowerExpand``

```
Sqrt[a x] Sqrt[b x] // PowerExpand
```

> ```
> Sqrt[a] Sqrt[b] x
> ```

Comment: This is equivalent to assuming a and b being reals. According to the documentation, PowerExpand always assumes real numbers and integer exponents.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all answers. This is one that fits my needs the most.

Answer (score 8):

I am answering this up to the letter: (1) combining powers of x, (2) grouping a and b under the same square root.

```
Simplify[Sqrt[a x] Sqrt[b x], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> Sqrt[a b] x

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[a x] Sqrt[b x], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> Sqrt[a b] x

```
Refine[Sqrt[a x ] Sqrt[b x ], Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0}]
```

> Sqrt[a b] x

```
Refine[Sqrt[a x ] Sqrt[b x ], a > 0 && b > 0]
```

> Sqrt[a b] x

Comment: It seems that when using `Simplify` and `FullSimplify`, we can get the result with setting any 2 of the 3 variables as a nonnegative number, for example, `{x >= 0, b > 0}` is also available, but I don't know the exact reason…

Comment: @xzczd My guess is, in your case, **a** is left alone and **b** brought under Sqrt[a] as positive number.

Comment: Just now, I accidentally found that if _b_ is a certain positive number, `Simplify` , `FullSimplify` and `Refine` won't work 囧: `b = 2; Simplify[Sqrt[a x] Sqrt[b x], x > 0 && a > 0]`, the result is: `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a] x`

Comment: @xzczd: That's because Mathematica pulls the factor out during normal evaluation: `Sqrt[2 a]` evaluates to `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[a]`. Thus even if `Simplify` should combine them, you'll never see that because subsequent evaluation will undo it.

Comment: @celtschk then, what if I want to get `Sqrt[2 a] x`?

Comment: @xzczd: Note that the internal form (as revealed by `FullForm`) does not contain `Sqrt` *at all.* That's only the way it is displayed. So maybe there's a way to get it displayed differently by changing `ToBoxes` or `Format`.